# python emailing wrapper similar to swiftmailer/phpmailer

Tags: python, email

Is there something like Swiftmailer or PHPMailer in python? I really miss those tools lol and I only find little toys and snippets on the net. Anyone with a good wrapper?

Comment: What is the problem with the combination of the email + sendmail module of Python???

Comment: I can ask the same thing to the guy who wrote swiftmailer, doctrine or sqlalchemy. The problem is 'time' and efficiency. Such tools exist to ease the path of a project.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the PHPMailer examples from GitHub, it seems that the main difference seems to be that only module is needed instead of two. Doug Hellman's Python Module of the Week covers smtplib pretty well, which is needed for sending (would prove a URL but I am limited to the number I can post). For the email module, the best documentation I've seen so far is from docs.python.org.

Anyway, to answer your question on an easier e-mail library, try the mailer module; you can find it [here](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2009/03/15/a-module-to-send-email-simply-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy to create one yourself, or you can take something like [flask-mail](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail), and remove the flask dependency (its really just a matter of editing two or three lines in the file), and use that.